Two definitions of the classifying bundle over a Grasmannian
In Hatcher's note Vector Bundles and K-theory (https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf), the Grassmannian $G_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ for $n\leq k$ is defined to be the set of all $n$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^k$. The classifying bundle over $G_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ is defined by $E_n(\mathbb{C}^k)=\{(g,v)\in G_n(\mathbb{C}^k)\times \mathbb{C}^k:v\in g\}$.
In Atiyah's book K-theory, the Grassmannian $G_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ is defined to be the set of all codimension $n$ subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^k$. The classifying bundle $E_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ is defined by the exact sequence $0 \to F_n(\mathbb{C}^k)\to G_n(\mathbb{C}^k)\times \mathbb{C}^k\to E_n(\mathbb{C}^k)\to 0$ where $F_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ is the bundle $F_n(\mathbb{C}^k)=\{(g,v)\in G_n(\mathbb{C}^k)\times \mathbb{C}^k:v\in g\}$.
Thus in both definitions $E_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ is a vector bundle of rank $n$, but over a different base space. But in both books it is proven that for a nice topological space $X$, the map $[X,G_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)] \to \text{Vect}_n(X)$, $[f]\mapsto f^*(E_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty))$, is a bijection. So I'm wondering these two definitions of $E_n(\mathbb{C}^k)$ should be essentially the same, in some sense. How should I interpret the difference of these two definitions?

Yes, they are the same. In Hatcher's notation there is a standard isomorphism $$G_n(\mathbb{C}^k) \cong G_{k-n}(\mathbb{C}^k), \ L \mapsto L^{\perp}$$ by taking orthogonal complements. The definition of the universal bundle then essentially takes into account this identification.
